# Error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.1.1 (14B100) device - Xamarin Profiler

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, profiling

I am trying to do the profiling of my application in iphone device. It gives me the error:

> "error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.1.1
>   (14B100) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode
>   version and then connect this device to XCode to install the
>   development support files."

Note : The App debugging works fine using the same phone. Problem is only when I do the profiling.

The version details of the developing environment are below.

- iPhone OS Version : 10.1.1(14B100)
- Mac PC OS version : 10.11.6 (15G31)
- Xamarin Studio Version : 6.1.1 (Build 17)
- Xamarin Profiler Version : 0.38.0-0
- XCode version: 8.1 (8B62)

Comment: what iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: Are you able to profile the app on the simulator?

Comment: iOS 10.1.  I am not able to run the profiling on simulator also. Android profiling is working as expected. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82524/error-mt1108-could-not-find-developer-tools-for-this-10-1-1-14b100-device contains the details.